# AWS CDK - ImportError: cannot import name 'AssetManifestOptions' from 'aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema'

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

When trying to synthesize my CDK app, I receive the following error:
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myusername\PycharmProjects\rbds-cdk_testing\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aws_cdk.core import App, Environment
  File "C:\Users\myusername\PycharmProjects\rbds-cdk_testing\.venv\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\__init__.py", line 1260, in <module>
    from .cloud_assembly_schema import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'AssetManifestOptions' from 'aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema' (C:\Users\myusername\PycharmProjects\rbds-cdk_testing\.venv\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\cloud_assembly_schema\__init__.py)
```

I am using node version 18.0.0. Here's the steps I've done in creating my CDK app:

```
(FROM c:\Users\myusername\) 
installed nvm
installed npm 
nvm use 18.0.0
npm install -g yarn
npm install -g aws-cdk
cdk bootstrap aws://account-number/region 
cd .\PyCharmProjects\mycdkapp 
cdk init app --language python 
.venv\Scripts\activate.bat 
python -m pip install aws-cdk.aws-glue 
python -m pip install aws-cdk
```

I error out even when executing `cdk ls` as the runtime tries to run app.py which contains
\

```
import yaml
from aws_cdk.core import App, Environment
from pipeline import PipelineCDKStack
```

In checking whether the **init**.py file for aws_cdk contains AssetManifestOptions, I've discovered it is completely missing:
[image]

Am I missing something here or is this a unique bug that I am experiencing? Any help much appreciated! I am banging my head on this one.

Comment: I should also add that I have npm/nvm/node + CDK installed outside of the VENV that I am working in. Is it best practice to install these components AFTER initiating the VENV?

Answer (score 0):

Its the same here, I think the issue can be in wrong package version.
cloud-assembly-schema==2.50.0 contains AssetManifestOptions.
Can you please paste here output of

`pip list -v | grep aws`

Iam able to install 2.50.0, however it depends on other packages of the same version (see attach)
[image]
And I cant set up core package because there is no CDKv2 matching distribution at the moment
[image]

Comment: Please don't add "Me too" as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in a different circumstance:

```
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> cdk destroy
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:\Py\task-cdk\app.py", line 4, in 
> import aws_cdk as cdk   File "E:\Py\cdk-aws2\env\Lib\site-packages\aws_cdk_*init*_.py", line 1425,
> in 
> from .cloud_assembly_schema import ( ImportError: cannot import name 'AssetManifestOptions' from 'aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema'

To fix the above issue, I have run a few commands like below:
a) Changed configurations, because executable and command were pointed to a different folder cdk-aws2:

```
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> notepad.exe .\.venv\pyvenv.cfg
```

b)

```
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> .venv\Scripts\activate.bat
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> pip install -r requirements.txt
```

c) Checked $PYTHONPATH variable and set accordingly.
d)

```
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> python -m ensurepip --upgrade
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> python -m venv .venv
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> python -m pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Finally, the following commands worked without any error:
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> cdk --profile default synth
PS E:\Py\task-cdk> cdk --profile default deploy